# Selected value in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I try to selected values in my form with twig:

```
    {{ form_widget(form.item1, {value: "1" }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.item2, {value: "4" }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.item3, {value: "11" }) }}
```

This is working, but how can I pass variable argument ?

```
    {{ form_widget(form.item1, {value: myvariable1 }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.item2, {value: myvariable2 }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.item3, {value: myvariable3 }) }}
```

Doesn't work...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can't do it from Twig, neither you should.

Try assigning the `data` option of form field:

```
$builder->add('field', 'choice', array(
    ....
    'data' => 'some_existing value' <-- THIS
    ....
));
```

**Update:**

It seemed that the issue was with type mismatch: `1 != "1"`.

The resolution was to force conversion of `int` to `string`:

```
{{ form_widget(form.item1, {value: myvariable ~ ""}) }}
```

Comment: It's working with quote around the value: {{ form_widget(form.item1, {value: "1" }) }}, but how can I pass a value with a twig variable ? {{ form_widget(form.item1, {value: myvariable }) }} doesn't work

Comment: How did you assign your variable? Try putting `{% set myvariable = "1" %}` just before `form_row`.

Comment: Thanks jperovic, {% set myvariable1 = "{{ anothervariable}}" %} or, {% set myvariable1 = anothervariable %} doesn't put the content of the variable "anothervariable" into the variable "myvariable1"... How can I do that ?

Comment: `{% set myvariable1 = anothervariable %}` should work fine. After assigning the `myvariable` try putting `{{ dump(myvariable1) }}` and `{{ dump(anothervariable) }}` to see what were the values...

Comment: sorry I misspoke, {% set myvariable1 = anothervariable %} work fine, but what I need is to put this content value into the quotes. (anothervariable content 2), I need to put it in {{ form_widget(form.item1, {value: "anothervariable" }) }} into the quote, but if I do that, it's the text "anothervariable" that his set and not is value (2)...

Comment: Ah well, then, try doing this: `{{ form_widget(form.item1, {value: myvariable ~ ""}) }}`. This will force convertion of `myvariable` to string, thus, it will be quoted. No need for extra variable... ;)

Comment: So much awesome jperovic, it is exactly what I need !! Big thanks :)

Comment: You're most welcome. I'll update the answer for anyone who might stumble upon the question... ;)