# Cannot set default value for choice in twig template (Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, twig

I trying to set the default value in Twig template using;

```
{{ form_widget(client_form.countries_id, {'value': client.countriesId}) }}
```

the `{{ dump(client.countriesId) }}` returns 2 which is the value i wanted to set.

If i set like `{{ form_widget(client_form.countries_id, {'value': "2"}) }}` the value is correcty setted. The problem seems to be in quotes. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 Setting a default choice field selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073236/symfony2-setting-a-default-choice-field-selection)

Comment: I found a solution on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326400/selected-value-in-twig][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326400/selected-value-in-twig

Comment: Congratulations, now you know it isn't hard to search before posting same question :).